# Bootstrap 3 not working in IE8 (checked other answers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I've seen the other stack overflow questions on this subject and made sure I've followed those answers but unfortunately it still won't work.

I have a bootstrap 3 theme which looks fine in all browsers apart from ie8.
I've included respond.min.js and html5shiv.js on my hosting account (where all other CSS is) and in IE8 I can actually see the files, so the scripts are being loaded.

They're also being loaded after all my stylesheets before the closing `</head>` tag, any idea's what could be causing my bootstrap to not work on IE8? It looks like all media queries are working, apart from the ones that specify the width of the columns.

I really hope I'm looking into this much and it's a simple fix but it happens on another of my bootstrap 3 sites, thanks in advance.

```
<link href="http://alexn.co.uk/Lemans/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="http://alexn.co.uk/Lemans/css/append.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="http://alexn.co.uk/Lemans/css/font.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://alexn.co.uk/Lemans/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://alexn.co.uk/Lemans/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://alexn.co.uk/Lemans/js/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
```

A live link to the site can be found at 
http://lemansfitness.co.uk

I should note that I'm hosting all this on tumblr.

Comment: what exactly isn't working?  can you be more specific please?

Comment: @msturdy mentioned it but not in enough detail sorry - mainly widths, so 4 width column is 100% width, just like a 12 width column

Comment: Looks like it's a cross domain issue. Use the CDN source for Respond.js and the shiv:

  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


Look at the GetBootstrap.com example files. Respond.js is very particular, if you don't host it at a relative path AND on root level domain, you have to set it up differently.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar problem. As it turns out, the minified Bootstrap 3 css does not play nicely with Respond.js 1.4. Instead, you must use an earlier version of Respond.js (1.3 seems to work for me).

Naturally, you must also follow all of the steps set forth in the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#browsers). In short:

- Use respond js and shiv
- Don't use CDN's, just use locally hosted files
- Don't use @import or file://

Here's another description of the bug and short testing markup for it https://gist.github.com/outlast/8602357

Answer (score 0):

> BOOTSTRAP'S DOCS:
>
> **Respond.js and cross-domain CSS**
>
> Using Respond.js with CSS hosted on a different (sub)domain (for
>   example, on a CDN) requires some additional setup. See the Respond.js
>   docs for details.

This means set up a proxy as per the Respond.js docs OR host your CSS with a relative path on your own server, don't use an absolute path to it.

Comment: I've gave that a shot but no luck - the site's assets are hosted at alexn.co.uk, the site is hosted on tumblr.com and the domain is lemansfitness.co.uk - so CSS/JS = alexn.co.uk Domain = lemansfitness.co.uk and site host is tumblr.com - tumblr offer an assets uploader (so i can upload CSS/js to tumblr which would give the links of static.tumblr.com/sd45435) what would I do in this circumstance?

Comment: Respond.js has pretty specific instructions and setups, if your site does not fit into one the options then you need to change your site hosting set up since the way Respond.js works can't be changed.

Comment: I think I'm changing the way it's hosted so its all on lemansfitness.co.uk - for the mean time is there any alternatives that would work with my setup? I've tried css3mediaqueries.js but no look there either

Comment: No, those are the only two and the css3mediaqueries.js require instead of (atsign)media (min-width:768px) and so forth to be (atsign)media screen and ... which means all of BS3 out of the box won't work unless you do a find and replace and even then, it's so buggy. Written long time ago and Repond.js is just so much better!